# Changing the order of infinite sum

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm studying measure theory and integral and I have no idea how to solve this exercise of Bartle:

> If $a_{mn}\ge0$, for all $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$, then $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}(\le+\infty)$$

Comment: Show $\le$ first.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is there anything that is not $\leq +\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possible arguments via elementary measure theory. Both involve the fact that if $f\colon \Bbb N\to [0,\infty]$ is a function and $\nu$ is the counting measure on $\Bbb N$, then

$$\int_{\Bbb N} f \,\text d\nu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\le \infty.$$

With this fact, we can argue as follows.

**Proof 1:** Apply Fubini's Theorem to the function

$$ g\colon\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to [0,\infty), \quad (m,n)\mapsto a_{mn},$$

and you're done.

**Proof 2:** Alternatively,

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}
&= \sup_{N\in\Bbb N} \sum_{m=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}
= \sup_{N\in\Bbb N} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^N a_{mn}
= \sup_{N\in\Bbb N} \int_\Bbb N  \sum_{m=1}^N a_{mn} \nu(\text d n)\\
&\stackrel{(\star)}= \int_\Bbb N  \left( \sup_{N\in\Bbb N} \sum_{m=1}^N a_{mn} \right) \nu(\text d n) 
= \int_\Bbb N  \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn} \nu(\text d n)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{mn},
\end{align}

where in ($\star$) we used the Monotone Convergence Theorem and the fact that $0\le \sum_{m=1}^N a_{mn} \uparrow \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}$ for $N\to\infty$.